# Generic Add with Retrieve

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I'm trying to create a generic Add that will return the actual values from the DB, because some of the values might be calculated by SQL.

For example:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public string ClientNum { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Adress { get; set; }
    public System.Guid SysRowID { get; set; }
}
```

SysRowId is calulated at SQL as newid(). So, after inserting the new record I want to do a Find. How may I do that in a generic way?

So far I have this:

```
var newDBRow = CreateDBRow(tableIndex);
FillValues(newDBRow);
Db.Set(newDBRow.GetType()).Add(newDBRow);
Db.SaveChanges();
var entry = Db.Entry(newDBRow); //SysRowID is blank at CurrentValues
newDBRow = Db.Set(newDBRow.GetType()).Find(KeysNeededHere); //Unable to get the entity keys.
```

I tried to use the entry, but SysRowID is still blank at CurrentValues. Also, I tried to use the Find but it needs keys and I can't add the ClientNum since I want to do it in a generic way for all entities.

Comment: Are you using Code First or Database First model ?

Comment: I'm using Database First.
by the way, I ended by finding the PK in this way: https://michaelmairegger.wordpress.com/2013/03/30/find-primary-keys-from-entities-from-dbcontext/
but my SysRowID column at SQL saved a blank guid instead of executing the default newid(). I'm researching your comment. Thanks

Comment: I edited my answer. Check my answer :)

Comment: *If* you think a generic Add is useful, why don't you use generics?

Answer (score 1):

`DbSet.Find` method expect the value of the key. If `SysRowID` is not defined as your key this method will never return a value even if `SysRowID` has the correct value.

**Database First:**
If you are using Database First, then in your EDMX model just right click on your property `SysRowID` and click on **Properties**, then change the **StoreGeneratedPattern** value to **Computed**.

**Code First:**
If you are using Code First approach then you must decorate your property `SysRowID` with DatabaseGenerated attribute and pass `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed`as a parameter to the constructor of the attribute.  At the end you will have this code on your property

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public System.Guid? SysRowID { get; set; }
```

---

By doing this either you are in Code First or Database First, EF will know that this property is computed by the database and it will retrieve it after insert success.